# Changing RUN to CMD stops the container from working

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to add Glide to my Golang project but I'm not getting my container working. I am currently using:

```
# create image from the official Go image
FROM golang:alpine

RUN apk add --update tzdata bash wget curl git;

# Create binary directory, install glide and fresh
RUN mkdir -p $$GOPATH/bin
RUN curl https://glide.sh/get | sh
RUN go get github.com/pilu/fresh

# define work directory
ADD . /go
WORKDIR /go/src

RUN glide update && fresh -c ../runner.conf main.go
```

as per [@craigchilds94](https://medium.com/@craigchilds94/hot-reloading-go-programs-with-docker-glide-fresh-d5f1acb63f72)'s post. When I run

```
docker build -t docker_test .
```

It all works. However, when I change the last line from `RUN glide ...` to `CMD glide ...` and then start the container with:

```
docker run -it --volume=$(PWD):/go docker_test
```

It gives me an error: `/bin/sh: glide: not found`. Ignoring the `glide update` and directly starting fresh results in the same: `/bin/sh fresh: not found.`

The end goal is to be able to mount a volume (for the live-reload) and be able to use it in docker-compose so I want to be able to build it, but I do not understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably work for your purposes:

```
# create image from the official Go image
FROM golang:alpine

RUN apk add --update tzdata bash wget curl git;

# Create binary directory, install glide and fresh
RUN go get -u github.com/Masterminds/glide
RUN go get -u github.com/pilu/fresh

# define work directory
ADD . /go
WORKDIR /go/src


ENTRYPOINT $GOPATH/bin/fresh -c /go/src/runner.conf /go/src/main.go
```

As far as I know you don't need to run the glide update after you've just installed glide. You can check this Dockerfile I wrote that uses glide:
https://github.com/timogoosen/dockerfiles/blob/master/btcd/Dockerfile
and here is the REAMDE: https://github.com/timogoosen/dockerfiles/blob/master/btcd/README.md

This article gives a good overview of the difference between: CMD, RUN and entrypoint: http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/
To quote from the article:
"RUN executes command(s) in a new layer and creates a new image. E.g., it is often used for installing software packages."
In my opinion installing packages and libraries can happen with RUN.
For starting your binary or commands I would suggest use ENTRYPOINT see:"ENTRYPOINT configures a container that will run as an executable." you could use CMD too for running:

```
$GOPATH/bin/fresh -c /go/src/runner.conf /go/src/main.go
```

something like this might work, I didn't test this part:

```
CMD ["$GOPATH/bin/fresh", "-c", "/go/src/runner.conf /go/src/main.go"]
```

Comment: Cool glad to hear that. Happy coding in Go :)