# Unable to deploy golang app to Azure app services container

Tags: azure, docker, go, azure-web-app-service

I've tried a lot of Dockerfile samples to build my golang app, they're working fine running on local.

Here is the last one Dockerfile I tried

```
FROM golang:alpine
EXPOSE 80
RUN  mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o app
ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]
```

I push my image to my Azure Container registry and use it via App service(linux) Deployment Center.

errors I got:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the port listening to 80 (App service default WEBSITE_PORT)

add ENV to Dockerfile

```
ENV GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64
```

Change Entrypoint

```
ENTRYPOINT [/app/app]
```

finally works.

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/faq-app-service-linux#custom-containers)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve your problem in the following two ways.

1. According to your screenshot, you can add a startup command to the dockerfile.

   *Reference link:*

   [1. How To Deploy a Go Web Application with Docker](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-go-web-application-with-docker)

   [2. Changing RUN to CMD stops the container from working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842730/changing-run-to-cmd-stops-the-container-from-working)
2. Make sure your files have been posted to the scm website. After under wwwroot, use the startup command to start your application.

   ```
   go run main.go
   ```

   *Reference link:*

   [Step by step guide to deploy Golang Application on Azure Web App](https://medium.com/@durgaprasadbudhwani/step-by-step-guide-to-deploy-golang-application-on-azure-web-app-46ba3befb4c0)

Comment: I read the first link, seems the author uses linux whereas I'm using Windows. Hence I could not build image using his Dockerfile config

Comment: I see the log in App service that  shows the server port is on. Still getting 502

Comment: @FVBn That's weird. Adding a start command will definitely solve your problem. Then you can raise a support ticket for help on the portal.

Comment: Sometimes I got this error:

```
open .env: no such file or directory
```
I think I already COPY . . , dotenv file should have been copied to workdir. don't know why